# ¿Como hago para cambiar el nombre que genera firebase cuando registra los datos?

Tags: firebase

[image: firebase]
[una vez que llegan a firebase se genera de estos códigos como se muestran en la imagen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMFs4.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase no dispone de ningun metodo para cambiar nombres de nodos. Lo que podes hacer es en vez de usar `.push()` en la referencia de donde vas a poner los datos, uses `child(nombre_a_eleccion)` .

Igualmente no es buena practica almacenar llaves con nombres estaticos que podrian ser reemplazados por cualquier modificacion. Usando `push()` y los `UID` de los usuarios autenticados como nodos principales es la mejor opcion.